# Python Function is returning none although there is the original Value instead of copy

Tags: python, function, matrix

I have a code where I zero a column or row if it contains zero , I have my own function but when I use it it returns None , I made a copy of my matrix and performed changes on it and then I converted the values to the original one and yet I still get no return . my function shouldn't return values only update the matrix values. here's the code:

```
def ConvertMatrix(NumOfRows,M):
    for i in range(numOfRows):
        Col=len(M[i])
    M1=[[M[i][j] for j in range(Col)] for i in range(numOfRows)]
    for i in range(numOfRows):
    for j in range(Col):
        if M[i][j]==0:
            for n in range(Col):
                M1[i][n]=0                   
            for k in range(numOfRows):
                M1[k][j]=0                   
    M=[[M1[i][j] for j in range(Col)] for i in range(numOfRows)]

numOfRows = int(input())
M = [[int(item) for item in input().split(' ')] for i in range(numOfRows)]
M=ConvertMatrix(numOfRows,M)
print(M)
```

Comment: if you don't have a "return" statement, all functions will return None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConvertMatrix(numOfRows, M)` does not return anything which means it implicitly returns `None`. Hence

```
M = ConvertMatrix(numOfRows, M)
```

turns `M` into `None`. There are two changes you should apply in order to  make this mutation function approach work:

Change the last line in the function to:

```
M[:] = [[M1[i][j] for ...]  
# slice assignment mutates the passed list object ...
# otherwise you are just rebinding a local variable
```

Do **not** assign the function result:

```
# ...
ConvertMatrix(numOfRows, M)
print(M)
```